# Service Fabric local machine deployment fails with unclear error

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When trying to debug Service Fabric locally it fails during deployment:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project.TestServer.Contracts, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Project.TestServer.Contracts -> D:\Projects\Project.Test\Project.TestServer.Contracts\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\Project.TestServer.Contracts.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: Project.TestServer, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Waiting for output folder cleanup...
2>Output folder cleanup has been completed.
2>Project.TestServer -> D:\Projects\Project.Test\Project.TestServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\win7-x64\Project.TestServer.dll
2>Project.TestServer -> D:\Projects\Project.Test\Project.TestServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\win7-x64\Project.TestServer.Views.dll
3>------ Build started: Project: Project.TestServer.ServiceFabric, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Deploy started: Project: Project.TestServer.ServiceFabric, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\33c99d3358d005d142e356b6d*******_8f15e82c-1deb-4d62-b94a-196c3a******
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What this line could mean?

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\33c99d3358d005d142e356b6d*******_8f15e82c-1deb-4d62-b94a-196c3a******
```

Comment: You can increase the build logging level, tools => options => build & run => build output verbosity. Or you can try deploying with powershell. To see if you get a more detailed error.

Comment: Having this same issue, but not getting any more detail from build output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue for the past day or so, and I was able to resolve the issue by searching my OS(C://) drive for the first part of the key name {first part}_{the rest}.

I found a copy/original key in "C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys" and copied it over to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys".

After doing this the app was able to run and deploy again on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1022#issuecomment-696336353) by `ravipal` worked for me:

> The issue is that the ASP.NET development certificate being imported to Local Computer was incomplete. We are working on addressing this issue in the VS Tooling. Meanwhile, please use the following workaround which is needed only once per machine.
>
> 1. Export the asp net development certificate
>    `dotnet dev-certs https -ep "%TEMP%\aspcert.pfx" -p <password>` (choose any password)
> 2. Launch local machine certificate manager
>    [image]
> 3. Import the certificate that was exported in step1 (%TEMP%\aspcert.pfx) to both 'Personal' and 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' of Local Computer. 
>    Please use all the default options while importing the certificate.

> Now the deployment of the SF application will work.